# How to use aggregate function to calculate unique data in mongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb, aggregation-framework, aggregate

This is input JSON data which is stored in mongoDB like this

**Input**

```
[{
  'name' : 'user1',
  'date' : '23/09/2017',
  'deviceType' : 'Android'
 },
{
 'name' : 'user2',
 'date' : '24/09/2017',
 'deviceType' :'ios'
},
{
'name' : 'user1',
'date' : '23/09/2017',
'deviceType' :'ios'
},
{
'name' : 'user2',
'date' : '23/09/2017',
'deviceType' :'ios'
},
{
'name' : 'user1',
'date' : '24/09/2017',
'deviceType' :'ios'
},
{
'name' : 'user2',
'date' : '25/09/2017',
'deviceType' :'Android'
}   
]
```

*And Output is*

**Output**

```
   [{
    'date' : '23/09/2017',
    'iosCount': 2,
    'androidCount':1
   }, 
  {
   'date' : '24/09/2017',
   'iosCount': 2,
   'androidCount':0
  },
  {
   'date' : '25/09/2017',
  'iosCount': 0,
  'androidCount':1
 }
]
```

I have used an  aggregation function to performorm task.
suppose collection name is **users** then.

```
db.users.aggregate([{'$group':{
                               '_id':{'date':'$date','name':'$name'},
                              'count':{'$sum' :1}
                              }
                    }])
```

Output of this aggregation function does not return appropriate result.

> Let us explain more I am intrested only date suppose 23/08/2017 how many users are there and which type of device they have used either ios or android not count of device. let's say example like
>
> If date "23/09/2017" has input data like
>
> [{'name' : 'user1','date' : '23/09/2017','deviceType' : 'Android'},
>
> {'name' : 'user1','date' : '23/09/2017','deviceType' :'ios'},
>
> {'name' : 'user1','date' : '23/09/2017','deviceType' : 'Android'},
>
> {'name' : 'user2','date': '23/09/2017','deviceType':'ios'}]
>
> output
>
> [{'date' : 23/09/2017, totalIos : 2, totalAndroid: 1}]

Answer (score 0):

`$sum` requires you tell it what to sum. Is this what you expect the output to be:

```
db.users.aggregate([{'$group': {'_id': {'date':'$date','name':'$name'}, 'count': {'$sum': 1}}}])

{ "_id" : { "date" : "24/09/2017", "name" : "user1" }, "count" : 1 }
{ "_id" : { "date" : "23/09/2017", "name" : "user2" }, "count" : 1 }
{ "_id" : { "date" : "24/09/2017", "name" : "user2" }, "count" : 1 }
{ "_id" : { "date" : "25/09/2017", "name" : "user2" }, "count" : 1 }
{ "_id" : { "date" : "23/09/2017", "name" : "user1" }, "count" : 2 }
```

Comment: Output should be come in this formate
     [{
    'date' : '23/09/2017',
    'iosCount': 2,
    'androidCount':1
   }, 
  {
   'date' : '24/09/2017',
   'iosCount': 2,
   'androidCount':0
  },
  {
   'date' : '25/09/2017',
  'iosCount': 0,
  'androidCount':1
 }
]